# Value Error: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 166 input samples and 4 target samples

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, classification

I'm working with Keras DL library to classify the dataset of images. I've encountered an error while I was trying to train the model.

The dataset I am working on doesn't have a huge amount of data, so an example the training set contains 166 images. I am not sure about the error but I think somehow I must change the shape of the label set to fix it. Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D


DIR = '/home/.../'
IMG_H = 256
IMG_W = 256
IMG_CH = 1


loadFile = DIR + 'Img.npz'
X = np.load(loadFile)
trainImgSet = X['trainImgSet']
trainLabelSet = X['trainLabelSet']
testImgSet = X['testImgSet']

print('Shape of trainImgSet: {}'.format(trainImgSet.shape))
print('Shape of trainLabelSet: {}'.format(trainLabelSet))
#print('Shape of testImgSet:{}'.format(testImgSet))


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3), input_shape = (IMG_H, IMG_W, IMG_CH)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (3, 3)))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 1)))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64))

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', 
                optimizer='adam',
                metrics=['accuracy'])

model.summary()

#train the CNN
model.fit(trainImgSet, trainLabelSet, batch_size=10, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)



Here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/Code/DeepCl.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.fit(trainImgSet, trainLabelSet, batch_size=10, epochs=5, validation_split=0.1)
  File "anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1536, in fit
    validation_split=validation_split)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 992, in _standardize_user_data
    class_weight, batch_size)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1169, in _standardize_weights
    training_utils.check_array_lengths(x, y, sample_weights)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 426, in check_array_lengths
    'and ' + str(list(set_y)[0]) + ' target samples.')
ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 166 input samples and 4 target samples.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here,

- The number of training samples is not equal to the number of labels.
- There are 144 training samples but only 4 labels for them.
- The shapes of the training and testing data must have equal number of samples.
- Ex. training data has shape `( 100 , 256 , 256 , 1 )`.  Testing data should have the shape `( 100 , 1 )`.

Comment: The training set contains of 4 classes and each label is assigned to one class. Assume that there is 4 classes of dog, cat, car and tree, so there is a label for each class, like 0 for dog, 1 for cat and so on, what is wrong with it? Should I change it?

Comment: For 4 classes, you need to add 4 output neurons with softmax activation function. For the dog, the output would be ( 0 ,1 ,0 , 0)

Comment: You need to convert the labels to vectors. Use keras.utils.to_categorical( train_Y , 4 )

Comment: I've changed it as you said but doesn't work. This is the error: ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_input to have shape (256, 256, 1) but got array with shape (256, 256, 4)

Comment: You need to change the shape of the labels and not the image. Suppose, your labels size is ( 100 , 1 ) the  after converting them to one hot vectors the shape must be ( 100 , 4 )

Comment: I did everything and I came across with new errors. Can you tell me where should I change in this code?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I called:

```
X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(...)
```

instead of

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(...)
```

(Notice the 2nd and 3rd variables are swopped on the LHS.)

It resulted in me having data and labels with unequal length:

i.e. len(X_train) != len(y_train) and len(X_test) != len(y_test).